# How to get most relevant hit from a search form

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm making a search form for my webpage and have stumbled upon the following issiue:

```
animal

animal | country
----------------
Dog    | USA 
Cat    | Canada
Mouse  | Sweden
Snake  | New Zealand
```

in my search form i might want to search the following:

1) 'dog usa' or 'usa dog'

2) 'snake new zealand' or 'new zealand snake'

My guess that i must split up the input text, and somehow manage to get the right arguments search the right col.

Question is how would i make the SQL statement to get moast accurate and relevant hit?
Or can anyone advize me on how to do this?

Comment: MySQL features several modes of FULLTEXT search indices, investigate if those are for you. If you need something more capable, there's Lucene and stuff based on it like Solr and a number of similar projects that specialise on full text searching.

Comment: If you decide to use FULLTEXT search, make sure you have plenty of test data, as anything that retrieves > 50% of the total results is counted as a 'failed search'.  Default is < 3 (or is that 4?) letters as a search term is also deemed a 'failed search'.  Heads up, is all.

Comment: My table contains countries and animals in each cols, when i search "cat canada" it must match both words, and output the exact match..ofcource one animal can be in more than 1 country as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use full text search in `mysql`. For example,

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE MATCH(animal) AGAINST ('$your_search_string')
OR MATCH(country) AGAINST ('$your_search_string');
```

Comment: Both col's must match the search-string so if i type: cat canada in search box, i must check both cols if they match. dont think it does that by using OR statement?

Comment: Please look in to this documentation. This might help you: http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/9/3/18